# Visual Studio code. Terminal. Arrows don't work in Irb and Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, visual-studio-code, irb

I can observe really weird behavior of the integrated terminal in VSCode.

When I work with irb or rails console (for my Ruby on Rails project), the arrow keys don't work.
So I can't use my command history and even move the cursor right/left (what is really annoying).

OS: windows 10.

Meanwhile, if I use standard Windows command promt, everything works fine.

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it for VSCode?

Comment: Hi Ivan, what shell do you use? I have had issues since I started to use zsh

Comment: Cmd, power shell, git bash - every one has the same issue in VScode.